# Linqpad and WPF (System.Windows.Controls reference)

Tags: wpf, linqpad

I'm trying to build some live WPF/XAML examples with Linqpad

to create the Window() and other controls I need to reference System.Windows.Controls from linqpad...

I've try to add this reference with F4 but the System.Windows.Controls do not appear in the list... In VS 2010 I can add this reference... so it's proved that the .DLL exists

I've looked in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and nothing...
also looked in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF and nothing also...

There is a System.Windows.Presentation.dll in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF, but I try to include it and still doesn't work

?any suggestions

Answer (score 6):

Ok Solved it...

Just include
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework.dll

```
// and import namespaces
System.Windows.Controls
System.Windows.Documents
System.Windows.Interop
System.Windows.Media
System.Windows.Shell
System.Xaml
```

;=))

Comment: Can you share some of the code you used? I was wondering how I could use Xaml in Linqpad, so would appreciate some examples. (Or were you using LinqPad only for what could be achieved through code-behind?)

Comment: I'm using just or academic investigation... nothing too fancy... just proof of concept...

Comment: Right now I moved all my ''quick'' testing to RoslynPad (https://roslynpad.net/) and VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com/)...

They are both open/free products...
and leaved LinqPad...

(LinqPad is a paid-per-user... and even upgrade from version 4 to 5 is paid...)